# document.ready(function() is not working on android device

Tags: javascript, android

I am using document.ready() function it is working fine on windows and ios device but not working on android device . Please help me .

// min.js in js folder
               // jquery.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //
        $("#ios").hide();         // to hide ios div  to hide android div
        $("#android").hide();        // $("#iOSP").hide(); ios heading div
     var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;    
// user agent 
    if( userAgent.match( /iPad/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPhone/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPod/i ) )  // // user agent checks if device is ios 
    {
        $("#ios").show(); // when ios found showing ios div 
        $("#android").hide(); // and hiding  android div
    }else 
    { 
        $("#ios").hide();  // other wise hide  and  
        $("#android").show();  // show android
        $("#iOSP").hide();     // ios div

    }

// This code is running fine on ios device and also on desktop with os //widows7 

[enter link description here][1]
}); 


</script>
```

Comment: if you are using phonegap, you should check `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);`

Comment: No i am making api and in android app this page is added to show the div of android and in ios it is shown ios div . It is working fine on ios and windows 7 but not working on android device . what should i do ?

Comment: I am having the same issues with and Android 4.01 device.